# Why double quote in bash can't expand the ''~"?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried this at first:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

V8_FOLDER=~/workspace/v8

cd ${V8_FOLDER}

pwd
```

It worked fine, output is `/home/myname/workspace/v8`;

But when I tried this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

V8_FOLDER="~/workspace/v8"

cd ${V8_FOLDER}

pwd
```

There is an error occurred, the output is :
`./update_and_compile: line 5: cd: ~/workspace/v8: No such file or directory`

I thought the double quote is the upgrade version of no quote in shell script, why this kind of inconsistency exist? If there are something wrong here, what's the right way to cd in a folder in the shell script?

bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 3):

> I thought the double quote is the upgrade version of no quote in shell script, […]

You were mistaken.

The purpose of [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) is to disable the special-ness of various special characters. For example, if you have a file that's literally named `~` (which I don't recommend), you can refer to it as `\~` or `'~'` or `"~"`. (Or, since `~` is only special at the start of a word, you can refer to it as `./~`.)

It's important to use double quotes around expansions such as `${V8_FOLDER}` in order to ensure that various special characters inside the result don't get treated as special; but you can't use double-quotes when you actually want the special behavior that they disable, because, well, they disable it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `~` use `${HOME}` Any kind of quotation around the `~` prevents this tilde expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `~` with `$HOME`.

Comment: @SurajKumar, this answer's OPs question "what's the right way to cd in a folder in the shell script?"